# window.open() function opens two new browser windows with two different URL's instead of one URL in one window

Tags: javascript

Using browser IE9 and chrome.
trying to concatenate two url's to form a single url:
`host1 = "https://home-page.com"`  and `host2= "https://homet3-page.com"`.
I have used replace function as `host2=host1.replace("home","homet3")` to replace home with homet3.
but here two windows opens one with url as  `"https://home-page.com/list/self"`
and second  with url as `"https://homet3-page.com/me/myself/?browserOffset=0"`

Following is the code:
Javascript function and html code:

```
  

       function openWin() {
        var host1 = "https://home-page.com";
        var host2 = host1.replace("home","homet3"); 
        window.open(host1+"/id?"+host2+"/me/myself/?browserOffset=0");
       }
```

`<a class="list" href="../../../list/self" onclick="openWin()" 
       target="_blank">Click Link</a>`

Comment: Try using `encodeURI`

Comment: The second window appears because the browser is also opening `../../../list/self` in a new window (due to `target="_blank"`).

Comment: I would not use a `<a></a>` if you want to manage the link manually. Use a `<span>` or similar and CSS to make it look like a link. Less headache with default functionality. Though I assume setting `href="#"` and using `event.preventDefault()` could work too.

Answer (score 1):

it trigger twice because `<a href></a>` tag is triggering you to the new page, and so does the `onclick="openWin()"`. the easiest way to only trigger once is to changes the link tag to another tag such as button.

Comment: The easiest way is adding `event.preventDefault();` at the top of `openWin()`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why two windows are opened is that you are using `target="_blank"` attribute in you `<a>` markup. Remove this attribute, and edit your handler:

```
function openWin() {
        var host1 = "https://home-page.com";
        var host2 = host1.replace("home","homet3"); 
        window.open(host1+"/id?"+host2+"/me/myself/?browserOffset=0", "_blank");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer (7/9/2021) after struggling with this for awhile. One of the answers above said to remove the target="_blank" in the a tag, this did not work. I still got two windows opening in addition the current window I was on routing to the clicked link. What I found the fix to be was adding parameter to the function call:

```
$(selector).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank');
});
```

The preventDefault line prevents the default action which is for the anchor tag to send you to the link obviously. So, by preventing the default action you are only allowing this click function to go through.